# Retrieve Component Service COM+ Application configuration values via powershell script

Tags: powershell, com, component-services

I have a Component Service Application which values need to be retrieved by a powershell script, I've managed to get some configurations like the Pooling & Recycling values with the following script

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.EnterpriseServices"
$comAdmin = New-Object -ComObject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$applications = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")
$applications.Populate()
foreach ($app in $applications) {
   $appName = $app.Name
   Write-Output "Application Name: $appName"
   # Retrieve recycling properties
   $recycleLifetimeLimit = $app.Value("RecycleLifetimeLimit")
   $recycleMemoryLimit = $app.Value("RecycleMemoryLimit")
   $recycleCallLimit = $app.Value("RecycleCallLimit")
   $recycleActivationLimit = $app.Value("RecycleActivationLimit")
   $recycleExpirationTimeout = $app.Value("RecycleExpirationTimeout")
   # Output recycling properties
   Write-Output "  RecycleLifetimeLimit: $recycleLifetimeLimit"
   Write-Output "  RecycleMemoryLimit: $recycleMemoryLimit"
   Write-Output "  RecycleCallLimit: $recycleCallLimit"
   Write-Output "  RecycleActivationLimit: $recycleActivationLimit"
   Write-Output "  RecycleExpirationTimeout: $recycleExpirationTimeout"
   Write-Output "-------------------------"
}
```

The script above works perfectly fine, but I want to retrieve the value of the "Remote Server Name" inpu that is located in the "Activation" Tab showed in the image bellow: [image]

I've read trough the COMAdmin interfaces documentation in the microsoft website but I couldn't find this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [ApplicationProxyServerName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cossdk/applications#applicationproxyservername) property

```
$applicationProxyServerName = $app.Value("ApplicationProxyServerName")
```